# error in using github packages in namespace of a package

Tags: r, import, namespaces, package, roxygen2

I have wrote this in descriptive file of a package :

```
Package: Minoo
Type: Package
Title: Representing some especial graphs 
Version: 0.1.0
Date: 2017-05-20
Author: Minoo
Maintainer: Minoo 
Description: Functions for demonstrating some especial graphs
License: GPL-3
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: TRUE
devtools::use_package("factoextra")
devtools::document()
Imports: 
igraph ( >= 1.0.1 ),
network ( >= 1.13.0 ),
FactoMineR( >= 1.35 ),
factoextra( >= 1.0.4.999 )
Remotes: kassambara/factoextra
```

and while building that I get this error:

> ERROR: The build directory does not contain a DESCRIPTION file so
>   cannot be built as a package.
>
> Build directory: C:/Users/MINoOo/Desktop/PROJECT/CINA

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Moreover, when I run

devtools::use_package("factoextra")
    devtools::document()
in console, I get this error! and I totally don't know what to do?

> Error: Line starting 'factoextra ...' is malformed!

Comment: What did you name the file? Is it literally `DESCRIPTION` (with no file extension)? Did you start with `devtools::create()` or `devtools:setup()`? There is a `devtools::create_description()` function to start you off with a description file you can modify

Comment: Perhaps, this might be due to the missing comma after `factoextra` in the `Imports` section. But anyway, the whole file looks very different to other `DESCRIPTION` files. Please, check http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: @MrFlick I didn't add. I don't know where should I add it. This has been written in description file of the package.